# Call calendar and get the user choosed date Android

Tags: android, date, calendar

I want to create a EditText with "Deadline" title and when user clicks on it calendar should show. User choose the date and I want to put it in this EditText. How can I implement it on the Android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

take a look at this [page](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-date-picker-example/).
I think it's what you want.

Comment: oh....thank you very much...And I'm wondering if I can use standart Android calendar components...?